# Having trouble converting strings to numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having an issue with casting or converting my `varchar2` value to a number. The problem is that my `TO_EMPLOYEE` column (in `PROJ_NOTIFY_HIST`) contains both email addresses and employee IDs.

```
SELECT  NOTIFY.PROJ_ID
FROM    PROJ_NOTIFY_HIST NOTIFY
WHERE   NOTIFY.NOTIFIED_SENT = 0
AND     CAST(NOTIFY.TO_EMPLOYEE AS NUMBER) NOT IN (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID 
                                                   FROM V_ACTIVE_EMPLOYEE_INFO);
```

Is there any way to get employee IDs only, and compare them to my sub-query?

Comment: Column TO_EMPLOYEE data type?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Your going to need to show examples of TO_EMPLOYEE / EMPLOYEE_ID I think if one contains " emails and employee's ids"

Comment: Please check your caps-lock key, it seems to be broken.

Comment: TO_EMPLOYEE contains emails and ids.(data type:varchar)

Comment: EMPLOYEE_ID contains ids only. (data type: Number)

Comment: So you need to extract the ID from TO_EMPLOYEE, for advice on this (aside from redesigning the structure so its not necessary) you need to show sample data else this question is not answerable.

Comment: So you're looking for entries in your text field, which look like employee IDs (just because they are numeric? Or is there a length/format restriction?) which are not actually valid IDs - as they *don't* appear in the active-employee view? Is there another table/view that lists *all* IDs?

Comment: If you need to CAST a column like you do here, it indicates a poor table design.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want something like this:

```
SELECT NOTIFY.PROJ_ID
FROM PROJ_NOTIFY_HIST NOTIFY
WHERE NOTIFY.NOTIFIED_SENT = 0 AND
      NOT EXIST (SELECT 1
                 FROM V_ACTIVE_EMPLOYEE_INFO A
                 WHERE TO_CHAR(A.EMPLOYEE_ID) = NOTIFY.TO_EMPLOYEE
                );
```

The main thing?  Cast to a string not a number.

If you only want to limit this to values that look like a number, then:

```
SELECT NOTIFY.PROJ_ID
FROM PROJ_NOTIFY_HIST NOTIFY
WHERE NOTIFY.NOTIFIED_SENT = 0 AND
      REGEXP_LIKE(EMPLOYEE_ID, '^[0-9]+$') AND
      NOT EXIST (SELECT 1
                 FROM V_ACTIVE_EMPLOYEE_INFO A
                 WHERE TO_CHAR(A.EMPLOYEE_ID) = NOTIFY.TO_EMPLOYEE
                );
```

Comment: Agree with casting to string not number (clearly!); but this will include rows which have email addresses since those won't match an active employee ID either. I don't think the OP wants to see those, just IDs which aren't active. (As so often happens, it's not entirely clear...)

Answer (score 0):

You could test each `to_employee` value to see if it consists of only numeric characters, and only then try to convert it to a number and compare with your view. In recent versions of Oracle you can just use [`to_number()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_NUMBER.html) and use its `default ... on error` clause to prevent the ORA-01722. Or [`validate_conversion()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html) to do the test.

But that will only tell you if the value is numeric, not if it is an employee ID which you can then check to see if it's active. You could have other numbers in there that aren't supposed to be IDs, like phone numbers for example.

if you have a table that contains all employee IDs, not just the active ones, then you could cast those the other way, from numbers to strings, to find matches; e.g. if you have an `employee_info` table that holds all active and inactive employees, something like:

```
select  notify.proj_id
from    proj_notify_hist notify
join    employee_info e
on      notify.to_employee = cast(e.employee_id as varchar2(10)) -- use suitable size
where   notify.notified_sent = 0
and     e.employee_id not in (select employee_id 
                                from v_active_employee_info);
```

or

```
select  notify.proj_id
from    proj_notify_hist notify
join    employee_info e
on      notify.to_employee = cast(e.employee_id as varchar2(10)) -- use suitable size
where   notify.notified_sent = 0
and     not exists (select null
                    from v_active_employee_info active
                    where active.employee_id = e.employee_id);
```

If `v_active_employee_info` is a view over the `employee_info` table then you could skip that `not in` or `exists` look-up and instead directly test for whatever conditions the view is using to filter active employees.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -2):

Use case stetment to check should you convert it (field consists onlu numbers) or not.

```
CASE [ expression ]

   WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
   ELSE result

END
```